# ¿porque no puedo hacer un ValueEventListener dentro de un ciclo For?

Tags: android, firebase

quiero hacer varios llamados con un ciclo For a Firebase usando los  ValueEventListener o tambien con el ListenerForSingleEvent pero el for se lanza al ultimo valor del contador "i" y ahi hace solo un llamado y no de cada valor ,A que se de eso?

```
 for(i=0;i<CODIGOstring.size();i++) {
   Query q1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuario").orderByChild("Codigo").equalTo(CODIGOstring.get(i));
        q1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {......etc
```

O este:

```
for(i=0;i<CODIGOstring.size();i++) {
   mRootReference.child("Usuario").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {...etc
```

Comment: No se entiende bien lo que quieres hacer. Debería ser al revés, dentro del listener abres un bucle para leer los elementos que traiga la petición que hiciste a `Firebase` Si te planteas la cuestión de otro modo, ¿la `i` del  `for`, qué sentido tiene para `firebase`? me parece que ninguno.

Comment: Si observas los [ejemplos de la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data?hl=es-419) verás que el `for` está dentro, una vez has traído los datos de `firebase` entonces puedes leerlos. Tú lo estás haciendo al revés: metiendo la petición a `firebase` dentro de un bucle.

Comment: Hola, si ya he realizado varios llamados y poniendo el for dentro, lo que sucede es que necesito por ejemplo si tengo en mi firebase los datos: nombre, telefono, y Pais, estoy en la busqueda de todos los telefonos de los "Juan" que vivan en "Peru",y tambien de todos los "Pedro" que vivan en "Peru" y todos los "Carlos" que vivan en Peru y asi sucesivamente y para eso primero hice un llamado para guardar en un ArrayList todos los nombres y luego con un "for" quiero hacer varios llamados de cada nombre guardado en ese ArrayList para obtener los telefonos

Comment: A.Cedano todo este lio de codigo estoy haciendo porque el Firebase no me permite obtener todos los datos guardados en él, cuando antes  he modificado algun dato desde el celular o desde la computadora, asi que estoy subiendo datos de varios "Pedro" y de varios "Juan" y de varios "Carlos" repetidos y por eso estoy en la obligacion de recolectar todos los nombres en un Array List y luego eliminar los nombres repetidos y luego hacer varios llamados con un for con la cantidad de nombres que me queden en el Array para asi obtener los datos del ultimo nombre ingresado.

Comment: Hacerlo así tiene muy mal aspecto. Estás organizando tus datos de una forma no óptima lo cual podría redundar en una mala experiencia de usuario cuando la app crezca, por ejemplo, lentitud para recuperar cierta información. Creo que debes reflexionar seriamente sobre cómo debes estructurar la base de datos. Ten en  cuenta que `firebase` rompe muchos esquemas tradicionales de organización de datos. Debes tener muy claro [lo que se explica aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?hl=es) hay ejemplos concretos que puedes aplicar en tu caso.

Comment: Ok muchas gracias A.Cedano. Me podrias ayudar diciendome porque si modifico algun dato en el Firebase ya no permite recuperar toda la informacion guarada en el? A mi forma de verlo, creo que es una limitacion de Firebase ya que es algo comun que alguien quiera modificar un dato y luego obtener toda la base de datos. Agradeceria tu respuesta, siento que me expandira la forma de ver Firebase.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu comentario. Aunque creo que te equivocas en esto: *ya que es algo comun que alguien quiera modificar un dato y luego obtener toda la base de datos*. Es muy raro que se requiera *obtener toda la base de datos*. Generalmente la información de la base de datos se obtiene por partes, según las necesidades, por ejemplo: todos los registros que tienen nombre `Juan`, todas las compras del mes de noviembre, los últimos cinco registros, etc. Es muy raro que se requiera en algún momento obtener toda la base de datos.

Comment: Ah ya entiendo como lo enfocas amigo. Muchas gracias, seguire leyendo mas sobre Firebase. :)